# unable to recognize the cause of error using load data infile

Tags: mysql, sql

i am loading data into a table inside a stored procedure whose file name is passed as a parameter.

```
 select @load_config:= concat('load data local infile ',config_file,' into table config fields terminated by \',\' lines terminated by \n');
 prepare stm from @load_config;
```

for this i am getting an error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '/mnt/appln/mysql/dvdbuser/config.csv into table config fields terminated by ',' ' at line 1
>   i tried this as well

```
 select @load_config:= concat('load data local infile \'',config_file,'\' into table config fields terminated by \',\' lines terminated by \n');
 prepare stm from @load_config;
```

for which i got the error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

to be honest i am lost and i don't know where i am messing up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\` is the beginning of an escape sequence.

The first problem is most likely the lack of escaping single quotes. So when you do `\'` it translates into a single quote thus terminating that block that is not closed. As it is closed now, you get a syntax error due to the string fragment that remain. You would need to do `\\'` which would bring in a slash and not foobar the single quote after that.

See the Mysql manual page for the table of escape sequences at [String Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html).

Even still, this whole thing will not work. Because `LOAD DATA INFILE` is not supported in stored procedures, events, and the like. It is a sad thing, but allegedly for security reasons. It will generate an error 42000 or the similar.

> Error: This command is not supported in the prepared statement
>   protocol yet

A workaround is to use UDF's which require you to modify your mysql environment, or to create an external process for such trivial things which is what I do.

Comment: yes i did encounter that problem , i wanted to pass file as a parameter looks like i can't do that now anyways nice answer

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html) to assign a value to a variable:

```
SET @load_config:= concat('load data local infile ',config_file,' into table config
    fields terminated by \',\' lines terminated by \n');
```

Comment: I totally missed the `SET` part of the problem. See, I am stalking you, to reward you for your hard work on this site.